# Partial img lazy load with WP 5.5

Tags: images

I have upgraded to WP 5.5, however the majority of the images have no `loading="lazy"` attribute. These images are managed by 3rd party plugins, such as Slider Revolution, Essential Grid or Siteorigin...

Could it be the plugins are disabling lazy load somehow?

Comment: You would need to ask each developer. Lazyloading will only be added automatically if they load images a certain way.

Comment: Maybe they do this using Javascript `onLoad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not the `loading="lazy"` attribute will be added to images from these plugins depends entirely on how those plugins are outputting their images. As outlined in [this](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/14/lazy-loading-images-in-5-5/) blog post, WordPress 5.5 only adds the `loading="lazy"` attribute automatically to the following images:

> - images within post content (`the_content`)
> - images within post excerpts (`the_excerpt`)
> - images within text widgets (`widget_text_content`)
> - avatar images (`get_avatar`)
> - template images using [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/)    (`wp_get_attachment_image`)

So if these plugins are not adding images to the post content directly, or using the `wp_get_attachment_image()` function, then their images will likely not get this attribute. From experience I can say that many plugins and themes fail to use `wp_get_attachment_image()` even when it would be appropriate, and thus miss out on these features.

Adding the attribute to the images should be trivial, but whether that's something you could do yourself, or something the plugin's developer would need to do, is something that would be specific to each plugin. You will need to approach each plugin's developer, or consult the their developer resources, to find out. WordPress 5.5 is quite fresh though, so you may just want to give it a little time before plugins add support.